# Have an MSAccess database as a live feed to MySQL

Tags: mysql, ms-access, mysql-workbench

I am creating a MYSQL database.  I want to be able to have a table that is essentially a live link to an MSAccess database used elsewhere in the business.  That would provide the core users/clients information and then I would use that to drive the functionality within the new database.  I can connect MSAccess in MySQL or import it, but is there a way to do it as a linked table into MySQL

Edit:  Just to make it clear- the MYSQL needs to pull the data from the MSAccess dB

Comment: You should store the data in the MySQL and use MS Access db + odbc connector to create linked tables and read/write contents from/to MySQL. Not the other way.

Comment: The issue is that the Access dab is a different part of the business and cannot just be moved across.  So while I want to put new functionality in for a different section of the business I have to pull data from there into the MySQL dB

Comment: You cannot "pull". You have to link the mysql in ms access and push from access to mysql.

Comment: Pity- I'll have to do timed datadumps from access and then have regular jobs run in the MySQL to import.  Not a complete disasyer, just messy

Answer (score -1):

Business wise you have to make a feed API online that gets information from the mysql DB in feeds form (either json or xml).
second step is to read from the feeds and insert or update your data in the MSAccess